# Binary to integer, python, dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, binary, converters

I have a dictionary where the keys are binary strings. What I want to do is to convert the 
binary  strings into ordinary numbers, integer.

How do I do this with for all of the keys in the dict? I have thought about a for-loop, but unsure on how it would look.

```
d={'000': 'A', '001': 'B', '010': 'C'}
```

output

0
1
2
 instead of the binary

Comment: "I have thought about a for-loop, but unsure on how it would look." - just start to write it, it will come naturally...

Comment: as a sidenote: do *not* overwrite builtins (`dict`).

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: i just named it dict here hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> dict={'000': 'A', '001': 'B', '010': 'C'}
>>> 
>>> [int(ele, 2) for ele in dict]
[2, 1, 0]
>>> # getting this shuffled, since the `dict items` are `random`
>>>
>>> {int(k, 2): v for k, v in dict.items()}
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is an list comprehension together with the builtin int function:

```
>>> d = {'000': 'A', '001':'B', '111':'C'}
>>> list(int(x, 2) for x in d.keys())
[0, 1, 7]
```

The int function has a second argument that is the base of the number you want to convert. For binary use 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'000': 'A', '001': 'B', '010': 'C'}
>>> dict((int(a,2),b) for (a,b) in d.iteritems())
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}
```